# wicket/Jetty: avoid creation of new Http Sessions for liveness requests

Tags: session, jetty, wicket, livenessprobe

I'm developing a Wicket application (wicket 8) and for containerizing it, I'm adding a liveness endpoint like `GET /probe/` which I handle in a dummy ProbeApplication (non-authenticating Application) returning an empty page. All goes OK, but for every request the Jetty framework creates a new HttpSession, returning to the first request

```
302 Found
Location: http://localhost:8888/probe/;jsessionid=node01t8hgfnbo8d8rgpyws9neqguv0.node0?0
```

The session expiration takes hours (I want long sessions for my users), so application accumulates O(10k) empty Sessions which I'd like to avoid.
Is there a way not to create a Session when handling certain type of requests and just return `200 OK`?

P.S. I realized that I'm talking here not about wicket WebSession objects, but about HttpSession created by Jetty servlet container, and my application Session is also created. So the question should read like: how to invalidate Jetty HttpSession for particular endpoint at the end of request, or how to disable session tracking for it.

```
public class WebApplicationProbe extends WebApplication {   
@Override public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() {
        return org.apache.wicket.util.tester.DummyHomePage.class;   }

@Override public final Session newSession(Request request, Response response) {
         WebSession ws = new WebSession(request) ;
         System.err.println("Created new web session");
         return ws ;     }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code of the `/probe` handler! Do you use a Page, a Resource or pure Servlet ? You can set a breakpoint at org.apache.wicket.Session#bind() and see what calls it.

Comment: The `probe` handler application only redefines getHomePage returning a dummy test Page. Sorry for confusion, I updated the question: the session here is Jetty HttpSession, not the wicket one.

Comment: OK, then set the breakpoint in the Jetty HttpSession constructor. It must be the page that you use. Without showing us its code it is hard to help.

Comment: Added the code which shows that new WebSession is created each time when `GET /probe` is requested (in addition to creation of new HttpSession in Jetty).

Answer (score 2):

In Jetty, the `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession` is only created if the application (or its libraries) requests a session to be created.

In other words, you have a call to either ...

- [`jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getSession(true)`](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/blob/6.0.0-RELEASE/api/src/main/java/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.java#L463)
- [`jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getSession()`](https://github.com/jakartaee/servlet/blob/6.0.0-RELEASE/api/src/main/java/jakarta/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.java#L472)

If you change your probe to use `jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)` then no HttpSession is created if one doesn't exist already.